# Detailed Initialization Procedure class variable initializer

Tags: java, initialization, static-initialization, variable-initialization, static-initializer

I saw many confusing answers about the following point :

> Next, execute either the **class variable initializers** and **static initializers** of the class, or the **field initializers of the interface**, in textual order, as though they were a single block.

does class variable initializer include instance initliazer blocks ? and static initalizers include static block ? or does it only include variables ?

if not where does the order of intiliaztion come in the following :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2

eg. :

```
   static   {
        ...
    } // can we consider this static initializer ?

    {

    }// variable initalizer ?
    public static  String x="test"; // static initializer ?
    public String y; // variable initializer ?
```

Comment: Your question (as stated) does not make sense.  Please try to include code example to illustrate your case.

Comment: @PM77-1 this is from the documentation  I will provide an example